# using object in another js file

Tags: node.js

I am getting my hands on node.js and I am trying to understand the whole require/exports thing. I have the following main app.js file:

```
/app.js

var express  = require('express'),
    http     = require('http'),
    redis    = require('redis'),
    routes   = require('./routes'),

var app    = express(),
    client = redis.createClient();


// some more stuff here...
// and my routes

app.get('/', routes.index);
```

then, I have the routes file:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

I can of course use the client object on my app.js file, but how can I use the same object in my routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `req` and `res` are already being passed around by Express, you can attach `client` to one or both in a custom middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.client = res.client = client;
  next();
});
```

Note that order does matter with middleware, so this will need to be before `app.use(app.router);`.

But, then you can access the `client` within any route handlers:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  req.client.get(..., function (err, ...) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  });
};
```

Comment: can I pass it in another object instead of attaching it to req or res?

Comment: @johnsmith Not really. Express isn't passing any other objects, so including one requires closures, which is what [Problematic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/535666/problematic) suggested. Attaching to `req` and `res` is a rather common practice and is how most [Connect middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) work (Express being an extension of Connect). You can also find a real-world example of this type of attachment [in the `npm-www` project](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www/blob/v0.2.0/decorate.js#L125-L149), the source behind [npmjs.org](https://npmjs.org/).

Comment: that's pretty cool, thank you! I think iI'll stick with this as it seems a more elegant solution to me

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to export a function from your routes file that takes a client, and returns an object with your routes:

```
exports = module.exports = function (client) {
    return {
        index: function (req, res) {
            // use client here, as needed
            res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
        }
    };
};
```

Then from `app.js`:

```
var client = redis.createClient(),
    routes = require('./routes')(client);
```

Comment: is that the only way to do it? I'm not an expert at all so I have no idea what I am saying but that surely looks kind of complicated! :D